# Migrate Magento 1 to Mgento 2 with easy way?

Tags: magento2, migration

Can any one tell me what is the best way to migrate Magento1 to Magento2 full data.

It will very thankful in advance for help  .

Answer (score 3):

You can migrate all the data from Magento 1 to Magento 2 with the help of the data migration tool provided by Magento itself. Below is the link for step by step data migration official documentation.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Or you can choose any third party paid service to do it for you.